# No matching key/data pair found ("Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_NOTFOUND: No matching key/data pair found" error)

Tags: daemon, txpool

Running monerod.exe I get the following error:

2017-12-20 06:08:47.886 [P2P6]  ERROR   txpool  src/cryptonote_core/tx_pool.cpp:516     Failed to update txpool transaction metadata: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_NOTFOUND: No matching key/data pair found

Can you please explain what the issue is and how I can resolve it?

Thank you

More of the log:
2017-12-20 06:04:21.637 [P2P9]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:305     [76.65.209.116:47558 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1467705 -> 1468677 [Your node is 972 blocks (1 days) behind]
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2017-12-20 06:04:25.694 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[139.162.60.220:51810 OUT]  Synced 1467725/1468677[0m
2017-12-20 06:04:48.015 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[139.162.60.220:51810 OUT]  Synced 1467745/1468677[0m
2017-12-20 06:05:02.113 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[139.162.60.220:51810 OUT]  Synced 1467765/1468677[0m
2017-12-20 06:05:26.358 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[139.162.60.220:51810 OUT]  Synced 1467785/1468677[0m
2017-12-20 06:05:44.890 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[139.162.60.220:51810 OUT]  Synced 1467805/1468677[0m
2017-12-20 06:06:01.005 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[139.162.60.220:51810 OUT]  Synced 1467825/1468677[0m
2017-12-20 06:06:27.321 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[139.162.60.220:51810 OUT]  Synced 1467845/1468677[0m
2017-12-20 06:06:48.878 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[139.162.60.220:51810 OUT]  Synced 1467865/1468677[0m
2017-12-20 06:07:07.637 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[139.162.60.220:51810 OUT]  Synced 1467885/1468677[0m
2017-12-20 06:07:32.780 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[139.162.60.220:51810 OUT]  Synced 1467905/1468677[0m
2017-12-20 06:07:53.153 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[139.162.60.220:51810 OUT]  Synced 1467925/1468677[0m
2017-12-20 06:08:19.343 [P2P6]  ERROR   txpool  src/cryptonote_core/tx_pool.cpp:516     Failed to update txpool transaction metadata: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_NOTFOUND: No matching key/data pair found
2017-12-20 06:08:19.343 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[139.162.60.220:51810 OUT]  Synced 1467945/1468677[0m
2017-12-20 06:08:19.343 [P2P6]  ERROR   txpool  src/cryptonote_core/tx_pool.cpp:516     Failed to update txpool transaction metadata: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_NOTFOUND: No matching key/data pair found
2017-12-20 06:08:19.343 [P2P6]  ERROR   txpool  src/cryptonote_core/tx_pool.cpp:516     Failed to update txpool transaction metadata: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_NOTFOUND: No matching key/data pair found
2017-12-20 06:08:27.606 [P2P0]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:305     [103.26.196.210:54683 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1467945 -> 1468678 [Your node is 733 blocks (1 days) behind]
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2017-12-20 06:08:47.886 [P2P6]  ERROR   txpool  src/cryptonote_core/tx_pool.cpp:516     Failed to update txpool transaction metadata: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_NOTFOUND: No matching key/data pair found
2017-12-20 06:08:47.886 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[139.162.60.220:51810 OUT]  Synced 1467965/1468678[0m
2017-12-20 06:08:47.886 [P2P6]  ERROR   txpool  src/cryptonote_core/tx_pool.cpp:516     Failed to update txpool transaction metadata: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_NOTFOUND: No matching key/data pair found

Answer (score 2):

This is, most likely, a corrupted blockchain, for which I've posted suggestions here:

[Daemon shuts down on startup ("MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid" error)](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6586/daemon-shuts-down-on-startup-mdb-bad-txn-transaction-must-abort-has-a-child/)

Given that the error is somewhat different, I'll post those suggestions here too.

---

> Failed to update txpool transaction metadata: Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_NOTFOUND: No matching key/data pair found

This indicates that your blockchain is corrupted. You can first try to fix this as follows:

#### Windows

1. Browse to the directory `monerod.exe` is located.
2. Open a new command prompt. This is done by first making sure your cursor isn't located on any of the files and subsequently doing SHIFT + right click. It will give you an option to "Open command window here". If you're using Windows 10, it'll likely give you an option to open the Powershell.
3. Now type `monerod.exe --db-salvage`
4. If you're using the Powershell, type `.\monerod.exe --db-salvage`
5. If that doesn't work, type `./monerod.exe --db-salvage`
6. If that doesn't work you, unfortunately, have to resync from scratch. This is done by deleting `data.mdb` from `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb`, which will trigger the resync.
7. Note that `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb` is a hidden directory. Thus, you have to manually use the explorer to navigate to it.

#### Linux and Mac OS X:

1. Browse to the directory `monerod` is located.
2. Open a new terminal.
3. Now type `./monerod --db-salvage`
4. If that doesn't work you, unfortunately, have to resync from scratch. This is done by deleting `data.mdb` from `~/.bitmonero`, which will trigger the resync.
5. Note that `~/.bitmonero` is, by default, a hidden directory. On Mac OS X you can typically use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to unhide directories, whereas on Linux you can typically use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide directories.

---

Lastly, as a general piece of advice, if you need to shut down your PC, first shut down `monerod` gracefully by typing `exit` (if you're using the CLI) or click on the `x` (right top) if you're using the GUI. Otherwise, you might corrupt the blockchain again and you'd have to start all over again.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what part of the code is calling this (your log does not give enough info to tell), it's either a corrupted blockchain, or a harmless message which is fixed by https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/2971